# Angular Chart X-axis Text label overlap on each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have use https://github.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts this code with ionic framework i got result properly but unfortunately my x-axis chart text label overlap on each other.

**Current Output :**

[image]

**Expected :**

[image]

Comment: I think it may be the case that your graphs are shrinking according to the screen size: could you check if you have the same problem on tablet, with larger screen?

Comment: yes problem due to screen resolution but how will i avoid this..

Comment: I am not really able to check it now, but you could add either scroll in x-axis: but this would imply totally different UX..

Comment: ok , but no another way to handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of horizontal label use vertical label on x-axis.For more details check to [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels/grid) and [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/angular-charts-inside-ionic/610) or [here](http://demos.componentone.com/wijmo/5/Angular/FlexChartIntro/FlexChartIntro/)